# React Router renders two components on the same page

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-router

I've looked at the other questions similar to this, and none of them seem to solve this.

I want to use react router to link to another page.

This is the return of my component:

```
          <NativeRouter>
            <View style={styles.container}>
                <TextInput
                    onChangeText={value => this.onChangeText('username', value)}
                    style={styles.input}
                    placeholder='username'
                />
                <TextInput
                    onChangeText={value => this.onChangeText('password', value)}
                    style={styles.input}
                    secureTextEntry={true}
                    placeholder='password'
                />
                <Button style={styles.button} title="Sign In" onPress={this.signIn.bind(this)} />
                <TextInput
                    onChangeText={value => this.onChangeText('confirmationCode', value)}
                    style={styles.input}
                    placeholder='Confirmation Code'
                />
                <Button style={styles.button} title="Confirm Sign In" onPress={this.confirmSignIn.bind(this)} />

                <Link to='/forgotPassword'>
                    <Text>Forgot Password</Text>
                </Link>
                <Switch>
                    <Route path='/forgotPassword' component={ForgotPassword} />
                </Switch>
            </View>
          </NativeRouter>
```

Whenever I click on the link, the link renders the ForgotPassword component on the same page.

Ideas?

This is inside my app.js.

```
        <Switch>
          <Route path="/signin" component={SignIn} />
          <Route path="/forgotPassword" component={ForgotPassword} />
        </Switch>
        </View>
```

Comment: All react router does is mount and unmount components according to whether the path matches the current URL.  So here, your `ForgotPassword` component will mount if the url is /forgotPassword - If you don't want your log-in form to show, you should wrap it in a new component and mount using a separate route.

Comment: Your code define nested routing which rendered the forgetpassword components inside parent component.

Comment: @JordanBurnett how would i do that?

Answer (score 0):

the `Route` inside your component will get replaced with `ForgoPassword` component when the `url` matches, You should define the routes in the parent component

Example

```
import React from "react";
import { StyleSheet, Text, View, AppRegistry } from "react-native";
import { NativeRouter, Route, Link } from "react-router-native";

const Home = () => <Text style={styles.header}>Home</Text>;
const SignIn = () => <Text style={styles.header}>SignIn</Text>;
const ForgotPassword = () => <Text style={styles.header}>ForgotPassword</Text>;

const App = () => (
  <NativeRouter>
    <View style={styles.container}>
      <View style={styles.nav}>
        <Link to="/" underlayColor="#f0f4f7" style={styles.navItem}>
          <Text>Home</Text>
        </Link>
        <Link to="/signIn" underlayColor="#f0f4f7" style={styles.navItem}>
          <Text>Sign In</Text>
        </Link>
        <Link
          to="/forgotPassword"
          underlayColor="#f0f4f7"
          style={styles.navItem}
        >
          <Text>Forgot Password</Text>
        </Link>
      </View>

      <Route exact path="/" component={Home} />
      <Route path="/signIn" component={SignIn} />
      <Route path="/forgotPassword" component={ForgotPassword} />
    </View>
  </NativeRouter>
);

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    marginTop: 25,
    padding: 10
  },
  header: {
    fontSize: 20
  },
  nav: {
    flexDirection: "row",
    justifyContent: "space-around"
  },
  navItem: {
    flex: 1,
    alignItems: "center",
    padding: 10
  },
  subNavItem: {
    padding: 5
  },
  topic: {
    textAlign: "center",
    fontSize: 15
  }
});

AppRegistry.registerComponent("MyApp", () => App);
```

[sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/y6rgz)

Comment: Can you adjust you example to show what it would look like in separate components? App.js and SignIn.

Comment: @schoenbl I've updated the answer and the [sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/pjwnl) to show you how you can include components on every page like i did with `Nav` this is inside `Router` and to include other components through the `Route` inside `Switch`

Comment: that's not what I mean. What I need to see is how to structure it in the parent component App.js. I don't want a nav bar. I want Signin to link to ForgotPassword in a completely different page.

Comment: @schoenbl `SignUp` `Login` and `ForgotPassword`  are different pages

Comment: You don't get what I'm saying. I need one App.js component and one SignIn.js component; that's what I don't get, i.e., how to structure it in different components. All of your info is in one. I added what's inside my app.js

Comment: @schoenbl my `App` component control the routes, 'What component should i render when the user hits this router', every functional component in my example act like a different page which you should replace with your own components

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/195143/discussion-between-schoenbl-and-asaf-aviv).